# how can I put consecutive numbers in fields? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this code

```
 $queryF = "SELECT * FROM bot_pedidos WHERE id_origen = '1587871428' AND id_pedido_enc = 0";
$executeF = mysqli_query($conn, $queryF);
$fi = 1;
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($executeF)){
    $h = $fila["descripcion"];

    $msj .= $fi.$h."<br>";
    $d .= $fi++;

    $numeracion = $fi - 1;
    $updateNum = "UPDATE `bot_pedidos` SET `numeracion`= $numeracion WHERE id_pedido_enc = 0";
    $executeNum = mysqli_query($conn, $updateNum);  

 
}
```

I want to put in the field `numeracion` consecutive numbers like 1,2,3... But the problem is that the code update only with the last number.

[Image from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBaln.png)

so, how can I update the fields with consecutive numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4... no 3,3,3

Comment: You're not including any reference to an id in your `UPDATE` statement. Meaning that with each iteration you will update all of the records with `id_pedido_enc = 0`.

Comment: Exactly, but I need update with the consecutive numbers every record with id_pedido_enc = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SELECT` statement you have a specific filtering condition `WHERE id_origen = '1587871428' AND id_pedido_enc = 0` which selects only a handful of rows that match the criteria. But when you iterate this result set, you're using an `UPDATE` statement with only one condition:

```sql
UPDATE `bot_pedidos` SET `numeracion`= $numeracion WHERE id_pedido_enc = 0
```

So what does this actually do? It updates *every* row where `id_pedido_enc` is `0`. And not just the ones where `id_origen = '1587871428'` - literally any row with `id_pedido_enc = 0`, of any `id_origen`. They all now have `numeracion` set to `1`. In the next iteration they will all have `2`, then `3` and so on, depending on the size of the original result set.

What you really want to do is set the `numeracion` for each row *separately*. And to reference just one specific row in the whole table, it's natural to use its `id`. So, when iterating your result set, include that row's `id` inside the `UPDATE` statement:

```php
$updateNum = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `bot_pedidos` SET `numeracion`= ? WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $numeracion, $fila['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

If your primary key is not called `id`, then just change it to whatever it's called in your table.

Note that I have used prepared, parametrized statements instead of directly injecting the variable into the query string. You should always write your queries this way to [prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and also because prepared statements automatically take care of any necessary quoting of the parameters you pass.